# Conditional Statement in Apache 2.2 httpd.conf file

Tags: apache2.2

I'm looking for a way to add an "if statement" to an Apache httpd.conf file. I would like to know if it is possible to do something like this:

> -if connecting OS is Linux-
>
> EnableKerberosAuth true
>
> -else-
>
> EnableKerberosAuth false

Any help to get me moving in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably, those operating systems use some different module sets, so you can use IfModule condition.